# How to calculate the electric potential inside a charged cloud?

Tags: electrostatics, potential

Given charge density data at regular points inside a cube, how to compute the electrostatic potential at any point inside the cube. Taking the regular approach to compute the electric potential at a point (x,y,z) inside the cube I would calculate the distance between the given point and all points at which I am given the electron density and numerically evaluate the following integral-

$$\int \frac{\rho}{|r-r0|} \, dV $$

But what if I wish to compute the potential at a point at which I am given the charge density. Is this approach even valid inside the charged cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrostatic potential in this case will be a solution to the [Poisson's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson's_equation):

$\nabla^2 \phi = -\rho/\varepsilon$

It will be defined in the area of the "cloud", however to know the solution exactly you need to specify the boundary conditions.

Comment: I did think about that, but I dont have any boundary conditions to specify other than the fact that at infinite distance the potential will go to zero. The charge density that I have is the electronic charge density output of an electronic structure code. I need to use that to compute the electrostatic potential at a point, which lies inside this electron cloud.

Comment: The potential = 0 at infinity is a proper boundary condition. You can solve that numerically if you don't know the analytical shape of the charge density.